# Pivot table with if condition

Tags: vba, excel

I want to develop a pivot table.

I have tried a code that can do it as well.

but my requirement is , The code should look only for "AB", if the column AB contains Ontime, then it should look for the values in AD accordingly.

Could any one help me how I can do it.

```
  Sub mismatch2()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim pc1 As PivotCache
    Dim pt1 As PivotTable
    Dim ct1 As Integer
    Dim TableName As String

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Mismatch")
    ' get the pivot cache for the pivot table
    Set pc1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'BW'!R4C1:R1048576C32")
    ' get the pivot table range
    Set pt1 = pc1.CreatePivotTable(ws1.Range("A28"), TableName:="PivotTable15")
    ' get the parameter to count
    pt1.AddDataField pt1.PivotFields("Mismatch"), "Sum of Mismatch", xlCount

    With pt1

        ' declare the parameter for row and arrange the values in descending order
        With .PivotFields("Location in full form")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
            .AutoSort xlDescending, "Sum of Mismatch"
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With

        ' declare the parameter in the column and alighn the values to center
        With .PivotFields("Mismatch")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("G70 OK").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("G70 OK(R)").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("N/A").Visible = False

            pt1.TableRange2.Offset(0, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

[image: this is the sample data . So, the column AB I have mentioned is now in the second column of this sample data sheet. there you could find both ontime and forecast.]

[image: this is how my pivot output should look like. the row field is my column A and then it should look only for Ontime in Column B and give the count values of column C]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you show us with some data and the expected output? And what isn't working with the code you have.

Comment: For example is it only create the pivot is  Ontime is present anywhere in Column AB? In a specified set of rows? Is it, if present get values from here otherwise get from there? Also, do you really need that many rows going into your pivot source as shown (R1048576C32)?

Comment: And this  pt1.TableRange2.Offset(0, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter should be outside the With, i.e. after the End With and before the next EndWith; and can be just  .TableRange2.Offset(0, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Comment: @QHarr Yeah, I need all the rows as shown above. or it should detect the last row of the table and generate it .

Comment: @QHarr I am updating a sample data and output that I would like to have with my pivot table

Comment: please  don't exclude the row/column indicators. This could be anywhere in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very much like you just want a Page Filter of "Ontime /Forecast" for "Ontime"?

```
With .PivotFields("Ontime /Forecast")
    .Orientation = xlPageField 'This puts the filter above the main table
    .Position = 1
    .ShowAllItems = True 'You probably also want to include this for Row & Column
    .CurrentPage = "Ontime"
End With
```

(I would also recommend using either Range/Cell/End or a NamedRange with `Offset` to calculate your Pivot Source Data to be the 'correct' size, rather than having loads of blank rows.  The Named Range option lets it auto-resize every time you Refresh the Pivot)